# Shopify update plugin on checkout

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to send an API call to my shopify plugin on checkout? Specifically under the condition that the inventory for the variant is 0. I've been searching and searching but I find the documentation for anything like this is very sparse.

Comment: You can do this after the checkout through "additional scripts" on Thank you page or use a webhook.

Comment: Thank you @HymnZ this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

**No !!** As per my knowledge nothing can be done during checkout, since shopify itself handles it. Yes you can programmatically do checkout using [Checkout API](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/sell-through-the-checkout-api).
Now, if you want to restrict sell of product(or variants) if its inventory goes to 0(Zero), you can do it by selecting **Shopify tracks this product's inventory** in **Inventory Policy** of **Inventory** session in product settings. Refer [Inventory Tracking](https://help.shopify.com/manual/products/inventory#set-up-inventory-tracking)